# Inheritance problem of Member Entity in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem using JPA. I'm asking questions to get your help.

Member Entity is divided into two types:

1. OAuth2 users
2. General users (ID, Password)

The structure of them is as follows: Structure that inherits one abstract Member class each of the spherical classes.

```
Abstract Member Class
ᄂ OAuth2Member
ᄂ GeneralMember
```

Member is associated with an entity called an Item Entity. (1:N)

```
Item {
    @ManyToOne
    private member;
}
```

However, because the member field type of Item is Member.class, which is an abstract class, references an unknown entity error will occur.

What should I do in this situation? I must divide the General and the OAuth2 Member entities into two classes. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use the `@Inheritance` annotation:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Member {
    // common fields
}

@Entity
public class OAuth2Member extends Member {
    // fields
}

@Entity
public class GeneralMember extends Member {
    // fields
}
```

And finally

```java
@Entity
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne
    private Member member;

}
```

Using the `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` strategy will map all sub-classes to  the same database table. You can see what strategy suits you best, different strategies has different drawbacks.